# Simple analytic proof.

Tags: calculus, analysis

If asked to prove that $$e^x>1+x: x>0$$
Can I argue that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$
and this limit is approached from right side. However, am not confident how I justify it approaches from right side or whether that justification suffices.

Thank You.

Comment: So you probably don't know that $e^x=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, do you? Otherwise, simply study the function $e^x-1-x$.

Comment: Note that $\lim \frac{e^x}{e^x}=1$ while $e^x>e^x$ is *not* true.

Comment: Or for that matter that $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x}{e^x-1} = 1$.

Comment: julien, sorry. Sometimes I get really stupid. thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Use series expansion of $e^x$

> $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots >1+x$
>
> since $\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$ is positive quantity.

#### Alternative:

As given in julien's comment just study the function $f(x)=e^x-x-1$.Note that $f(0)=0$ and
take derivative of $f(x)$, you get $f'(x)=e^x-1$. It is strictly greater than $0$. Otherwise $f''(x)=e^x$. Clearly $f''(x)>0$ since $e^x$ is a non-negative function.Here you can conclude $f(x)>0 \implies e^x >1+x$ .

Comment: I guess this exercise is rather about using first derivative and monotonicity than Taylor expansions.

Comment: @DamianSobota: You may be right. But if someone know the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, then I think this will be the easier way to solve. It's my personal view.

Comment: Of course, you're right. It was my first thought about this question as well.

Answer (score 3):

By the Mean Value Theorem, 
$$\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}=e^{\xi}$$
for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$. Thus $e^{\xi}\gt 1$.

Comment: this is beautiful.

Comment: @user1709828: Not really, it just goes back to the *proof* of the result that is used in a couple of other answers (derivative positive implies increasing).

Comment: well, yeah. but even then, you never think that from the perspective of MVT.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x)=e^x-1-x$ we have
$$f(0)=0,$$
and for all $x>0$
$$f'(x)=e^x-1>0 \;\;  \Rightarrow \;\;f(x)>0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you know what a derivative is then take $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=e^x-x-1$ and then $f^{'}(x)=e^x-1$ so $f^{'}(x)=0 $ iff $x=0$.

Now for $x>0$ => $f^{'}(x)>0$ and for $x<0$ => $f^{'}(x)<0$.

From $x>0$ => $f^{'}(x)>0$ you get that the function $f$ increases on the positive real numbers so for these values ($x>0$)

$f(x)>f(0)$ which means $e^x-x-1>0$ ,$\forall x\in (0,\infty)$.